# iterate through a model map list in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I use `Spring MVC` in my project. In my controller, I add a list of values in to the model map.

```
model.addAttribute("BulkList", finalizedBulkList);
```

this `finalizedBulkList` is a `java.util.List`.

Now I need to iterate through the list and retrieve the values inside the list in `javascript`.

How can I do it?

```
var limit = parseInt(${BulkList}.length);

for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    console.log("value is = "+${BulkList[i]});
}
```

Above is What I tried, but not correct.

Comment: What are you intended to do with it in javascript?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not related languages (even though the names might make you think so). You can't just assume that JavaScript will be able to work with a Java list.
Why don't you use Java or Jsp for your UI ?

Comment: The  best solution would be to get this data via AJAX call, not by writing them as an array on your page. Secondly what ViewResolver you are using with your Spring MVC?

Comment: @Stultuske this javascript code is in jsp page, not in java code

Comment: @VPK I ned to check for non zero values in the list, and print them on a html div

Comment: Then why don't you use a servlet, build the list in there, and iterate over it in your jsp page ? There's no need for javascript here.

Comment: @Stultuske java code is in Spring controler. Now I access the list in jsp page. I need to do a task when the page get loaded.

Comment: @user3892439, I don't know about finalizedBulkList but if its structure is similar to any other list types in Java then `JSTL` tags are useful as shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `BulkList` accessible in Javascript. Javascript has accessible only the source code that is generated by your JSP.

For the list to be accessible in javascript you have to add the items to a javascript array. Something like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
var bulkListJavascriptArray = [ 
<c:forEach var="bulkItem" items="${BulkList}">
   <c:out value="${bulkItem}"/>,
</c:forEach>
];

for(var i=0; i<bulkListJavascriptArray.length; i++){
    console.log("value is = " + bulkListJavascriptArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jstl tags to iterate through the modelMap list object like this in your html or jsp code,

```
<div><c:forEach begin="0" end="${fn:length(BulkList) - 1 }" items="${BulkList}" var="bulkObject">
    <c:if test="${bulkObject != 0}"><c:out value="${bulkObject}"/></c:if>
</c:forEach>
</div>
```

To use this `JSTL` tag library you need to include it in your `jsp` page.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

Comment: Don't you have any idea of how to access this in a javascript. say I need to  print the values in browser console, How can I do so?

Comment: Then, instead of `<c:out>` use `<% System.out.println("Hello World in Console!"); %>`. The requirements you mentioned to use javascript to do so is I think is not a recommended approach by me as Javascript runs on client side and scriptlets on server side.

Comment: if I can get the length of the list like this, `var limit = parseInt(${BulkList}.length);` why cannot I iterate through the list in script